# Collect multiple files into single PDF

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dompdf

I use in my project [barryvdh laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) package.
Users might generate a PDF with some personal information, till here everything is ok:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('personalInfo', $userData);
$pdfFileName = "personal-info-{$userData['username']}.pdf";
return $pdf->download($pdfFileName);
```

Admin should be able to download information of users, and in case of selecting several users, instead of generating several files I would like to collect all users PDFs into a single file.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create like this below

For example you have `personalInfo` blade template which is now for particular user .So loop that view and store it in array like below

```
$pages=[];
foreach($userDataList as $key=>$userData){

$pages[]=(string)view('personalInfo', $userData);

}

$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadView('index', ['pages' => $pages]);
    return $pdf->stream();
```

then you can create seperate blade template to show these views.Here i will name it as **index.blade.php**

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    div.page
    {
        page-break-after: always;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
</style>

@foreach($pages as $page)
    <div class="page">
        {!! html_entity_decode($page) !!}
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**Method:2**

loop all user detail inside personalInfo blade template and at the end of each loop  add below  page break style

```
 <p style="page-break-before: always;"></p>
```

Example inside personalinfo blade

```
@foreach($pages as $page)
  personal information content
<p style="page-break-before: always;"></p>
@endforeach
```

Also i personally prefer laravel snappy for multiple page because it render faster than laravel dompdf.Only thing is to server configuration bit head ache if you are using windows
Ref:https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy